# How do i help for Ford Sync hear my demands better?

Tags: speakers, car-integration

My Ford Sync does not seem to hear me when i request to make a call, or when I tell it who to call..  is there something i need to do or change in my settings.  I have it paired with a iphone 4.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

My wife has a Fiesta with the Ford Sync system and she had a similar question when we first purchased it.  When she was giving voice commands she was directing her voice to her iPhone 4, either by holding it up to her face or holding it in front of her.  The problem though is that the Sync system uses a microphone built into the car, not your iPhone, for receiving voice commands.  I'm not at home so I can't say with 100% certainty but I'm pretty sure her microphone is to the left of the rear view mirror.  With that said the location may depend on whichever Ford model you have.

I would check the Ford's owner manual, it should show the location.

Comment: Thanks, I have gotten to the point of leaning into the dash hoping that it will hear me more clearly but this also has not worked... When I say "phone"  it responds "line in"?  and it is one big circle..  but thanks again

Comment: @Karen Yeah, I know the commands take some getting used to.  My wife has become pretty good at knowing exactly what to say for things to work but I still can't grasp it.  You might stop by a Ford dealer and ask for a hand with it.